# How to save a 3 channel numpy array as image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a numpy array with shape `(3, 256, 256)` which is a 3 channel (RGB) image of resoulution 256x256.  I am trying to save this to disk with `Image` from `PIL` by doing the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

#... get array s.t. arr.shape = (3,256, 256)
img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
img.save('out.png')
```

However this is saving an image of dimensions 256x3 to disk

Comment: Have you tried using `np.swapaxes` to reshape to a `(256,256,3)` array?

Comment: For those who get an compete noisy image after save, just use:  
`Image.fromarray(np.uint8(arr), 'RGB')`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The @Dietrich answer is valid, however in some cases it will flip the image. Since the transpose operator reverses the index, if the image is stored in `RGB x rows x cols` the transpose operator will yield `cols x rows x RGB` (which is the rotated image and not the desired result).

```
>>> arr = np.random.uniform(size=(3,256,257))*255
```

Note the `257` for visualization purposes.

```
>>> arr.T.shape
(257, 256, 3)

>>> arr.transpose(1, 2, 0).shape
(256, 257, 3)
```

The last one is what you might want in some cases, since it reorders the image (`rows x cols x RGB` in the example) instead of fully transpose it.

```
>>> arr = np.random.uniform(size=(3,256,256))*255
>>> arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr.transpose(1,2,0))
>>> img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
>>> img.save('out.png')
```

Probably the cast to contiguous array is not even needed, but is better to be sure that the image is contiguous before saving it.

Comment: How can I save this variable as an image file on the server?

Answer (score 10):

Try transposing `arr` which gives you an `(256, 256, 3)` array:

```
arr = np.random.uniform(size=(3,256,256))*255
img = Image.fromarray(arr.T, 'RGB')
img.save('out.png')
```

Comment: it works, thanks,  it is weird that the fromarray function treat the third dimension as the number of channels

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv to do merge three channel and save as img.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.uniform(size=(3,256,256))*255 # It's a r,g,b array
img = cv2.merge((arr[2], arr[1], arr[0]))  # Use opencv to merge as b,g,r
cv2.imwrite('out.png', img)
```