# how to save LL, LH, HL of a wavelet transform as a 3 channel image?

Tags: python, wavelet-transform

Tried to do a wavelet transformation using PyWavelets that described in this [link](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), here is my code:

```
import pywt
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('D:/gray.jpeg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #read gray image.
img = cv.resize(img, (256,256))
coeffs2 = pywt.dwt2(img, 'bior1.3')
LL, (LH, HL, HH) = coeffs2
```

Now, I want to save the LL, LH, and HH as a 3 channel image but I have no idea how to do that, could anyone tell me how to do that?

My other question: Is this only works with grayscale images?

Comment: Would [How to save a 3 channel numpy array as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600640/how-to-save-a-3-channel-numpy-array-as-image) maybe help you for the conversion?

Comment: thank you, tried that but not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Split the colored image into it's three color channels

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

coeffsb = pywt.dwt2(b, 'bior1.3')
LLb, (LHb, HLb, HHb) = coeffsb

coeffsg = pywt.dwt2(g, 'bior1.3')
LLg, (LHg, HLg, HHg) = coeffsg

coeffsb = pywt.dwt2(b, 'bior1.3')
LLr, (LHr, HLr, HHb) = coeffsr
```

Then you can apply wavelet transform to each channel separately. After that, you can merge the band of your choice (e.g. LL):

```
LL = cv2.merge(LLb, LLg, LLr)
```