# PIL: Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), mode='RGB') returns grayscale image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have converted a pytorch tensor of size `torch.Size([3, 28, 28])` to a numpy array of size `(28, 28, 3)`, and there doesn't seem to be any problems with that. I then try to convert this to a PIL image using `img = Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), mode='RGB')`, but the dimensions of the returned `img` are `(28, 28)`, when I expect it to be `(28, 28, 3)` (or `(3, 28, 28)`). I cannot understand why this is the case. I made sure to convert to uint8 and use RGB mode, as other posters have suggested online, however neither of those (nor using [np.ascontiguousarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600640/how-to-save-a-3-channel-numpy-array-as-image)) helped.

PIL version 1.1.7

```
# This code implements the __getitem__ function for a child class of datasets.MNIST in pytorch
# https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#MNIST

img, label = self.data[index], self.targets[index]
assert img.shape == (3, 28, 28), \
       (f'[Before PIL] Incorrect image shape: expecting (3, 28, 28),'
        f'received {img.shape}')

print('Before reshape:', img.shape)    # torch.Size([3, 28, 28])
img = img.numpy().reshape(3, 28, 28)
img = np.stack([img[0,:,:], img[1,:,:], img[2,:,:]], axis=2)
print('After reshape:', img.shape)     # (28, 28, 3)

# doing this so that it is consistent with all other datasets
# to return a PIL Image
img = Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), mode='RGB') # Returns 28 x 28 image

assert img.size == (3, 28, 28), \
       (f'[Before Transform] Incorrect image shape: expecting (3, 28, 28), '
        f'received {img.size}')
```

EDIT: Here is a minimal example. I'll leave the above for context in case it is of any help at all.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randn(28, 28, 3)
img = Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), mode='RGB') # Returns 28 x 28 image

assert img.size == (28, 28, 3), \
       (f'[Before Transform] Incorrect image shape: expecting (3, 28, 28), '
        f'received {img.size}')
```

`AssertionError: [Before Transform] Incorrect image shape: expecting (3, 28, 28), received (28, 28)`

Answer (score 6):

I think you want this, where the ranges of the RGB vales are integers in range 0..255:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Make random 28x28 RGB image
img =np.random.randint(0,256,(28,28,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Convert to PIL Image
pImg=Image.fromarray(img, mode='RGB')
```

Now check what we have:

```
In [19]: pImg                                                                                       
Out[19]: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=28x28 at 0x120CE9CF8>
```

And save:

```
pImg.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is a problem with my code as well I didn't realize, but not the main problem, which was trying to get the image dimensions to include color. Actually, I was able to solve it because of your answer - I realized that Image.size only returns width and height (and not # color channels) once I saw your ```Out size=28x28``` and your pImg is RGB. So thanks for that as well!